# Is there something like a reverse eval() function?

Tags: python, eval

Imagine the following problem: you have a dictionary of some content in python and want to generate python code that would create this dict. (which is like eval but in reverse)
Is there something that can do this?

**Scenario:**
I am working with a remote python interpreter. I can give source files to it but no input. So I am now looking for a way to encode my input data into a python source file.

**Example:**

```
d = {'a': [1,4,7]}
str_d = reverse_eval(d)
# "{'a': [1, 4, 7]}"
eval(str_d) == d
```

Comment: Can you be more specific by providing an example?

Comment: rather reverse `ast.literal_eval` then.

Comment: Not quite sure why you are trying to do this. It might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for which [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html) is the solution for the unasked X problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman Let's not casually throw around `pickle`, please. We're giving newbies the impression that pickle can solve their problem, without mentioning that it opens up their program to an arbitrary code execution vulnerability. That's how we end up with people sending pickled data over an unsecured socket connection.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Good point -- but of course `eval` has the same problems. Fortunately, the pickle documentation that I linked to has a very clear warning which is formatted so that it is the first thing you see when you look at it.

Comment: @JohnColeman Good point. But in my opinion, it is better to ask for the functionality you are looking for, because this way other people looking for that functionality may find it too. Even if they have a different problem to start with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
repr(thing)
```

will output text that when executed will (in most cases) reproduce the dictionary.

Comment: To elaborate: the *purpose* of `repr` is to return a string which, if possible, will reconstruct an equivalent object when passed to `eval`. That's why the Python REPL uses `repr` when printing objects.

Comment: this does not work for classes. eg: `eval(repr(Klass))` raises a SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's important for which types of data do you want this reverse function to exist. If you're talking about built-in/standard classes, usually **their** `.__repr__()` method returns the code you want to access. But if your goal is to save something in a human-readable format, but to use an eval-like function to use this data in python, there is a `json` library.
It's better to use json for this reason because using eval is not safe.
Json's problem is that it can't save **any** type of data, it can save only standard objects, but if we're talking about not built-in types of data, you never know, what is at their `.__repr__()`, so there's no way to use repr-eval with this kind of data

So, there is no reverse function for all types of data, you can use repr-eval for built-in, but for built-in data the `json` library is better at least because it's safe

Comment: Not all "built-in data" will work with JSON. For example, Python tuples will be converted to JSON lists, and Python dictionaries with non-string keys will be converted to strings or rejected. Python sets are not rejected.